# Xamarin IOS - how to include the existing sqlite database file into solution

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios6, xamarin

In Xamarin IOS solution, the standard code for sqlite database path is:

```
var sqliteFilename = "MyDatabase.db3";        
string libraryPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, "..", "Library"); // Library folder instead
var path = Path.Combine (libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
```

The above code is fine if the database is created from scratch.
but my question is how should I include the existing sqlite database into the solution, so it can be copied over to "Library" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include your database as a file in your solution, marking it as "Build Action -> Content".  In your code, you can access it relative to the root of your project (ie, "/mydb.db3") - then read it and copy it to your Library or wherever you want to place it.

Keep in mind that files bundled into your application are READ-ONLY.  You will have to copy the db to a writable path before you can write to it.